# CodeIgniter - form_dropdown defaults to multiple

Tags: codeigniter

Im having a little trouble with my form_dropdown in codeigniter, basically it ALWAYS adds the multiple="multiple" and i dont know how to get rid of it.

Here is the code im using to generate the dropdown

```
$js = 'class="users"';
echo form_dropdown('users', $users, set_value('users', $users), $js);
```

Is there anything i can add so that it doesnt automatically create it with the multiple option

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is related to your third option `set_value('users',$users)`

Since `$users` is probably an array, the set_value may be setting multiple options to `selected` and in such a case form_dropdown would generate the multiple property.

Try passing a single user value and make sure that works as you expect.

Also, check the out put from the set_value function to see if it returns an array instead of a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `set_value` here.  Just use the value you want selected.

```
$js = 'class="users"';
$user = 1;
echo form_dropdown('users', $users, $user, $js);
```

Comment: using `set_value()` here actual would be fine, it's the fact that he's passing `$users` which is the same array he sets as the options.  using `set_value()` here would actually lend itself to re-populating forms on validation failure.